# parallel celery blocking tasks

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, celery

I have an application in Flask that is CPU-intensive.
I would like the application to work in parallel, that's why I used celery. If the tasks are started and I do not wait for them to finish, they work in parallel. However, when I wait for them to finish (block), the next task starts after the previous one has finished

```
@myapp.route("/calc")
def calc():
    task = cpu_intensive_task.delay(30)
    result = task.get() # blocking
    return f'result={result}'
```

I also tried to run many workers, but the first task runs on worker1 and only after it finishes, second worker receives the second task

Can I do something to run tasks in parallel?

Comment: How many WSGI workers do you use? Even if you schedule your tasks on celery, each worker in your WSGI container will be blocked by the celery task.

Comment: I don't kow if I understand correctly, but I use waitress package: fire.Fire(serve(myapp, port=5000, threads=6))

Comment: Return the result of cpu_intensive_task in your cpu_intensive_task.